Find a formula for $\operatorname{tr} T.$
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Suppose $V$ is an inner product space and $v,w \in V.$ Define an operator $T \in \mathcal{L} (V)$ by $Tu = \langle u,v \rangle w.$ Find a formula for $\operatorname{tr} T.$
Here are some thoughts:
If $w = 0$, then $T = 0$ and $\operatorname{trace} T = 0$.
If $w \neq 0$, then extend $w$ to a basis of $V$.
All entries of the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis are $0$(am I correct?), except possibly the first row (or column I do not know which ? ), because $\operatorname{range} T \subset \operatorname{span}(w)$.
Therefore, the trace of this matrix, which equals the trace of $T$, is $\langle w, v \rangle w$ (I am not very sure from this formula it is just a guess, am I correct?).
Can anyone please check my bold statements and clarify them to me?

Try some concrete examples to test your guesses. E.g. $V=\Bbb R^2$, $w=(1,0)$, and various instances for $v$.

Note that $T$ has only one non zero eigenvalue.

The trace is a scalar and what you've written is a vector.

@copper.hat how will this help me?

@QiaochuYuan I see your point :) but then how can I solve this problem then?

How do you define trace???

The sum of the eigenvalues of $T$ with each eigenvalue repeated according to its multiplicity. @copper.hat so the trace is just the value of the inner product of w with v without the vector w?

Please edit your post to include a real attempt, not just guesses and questions.

@Hope Yes, but you need to justify that.

@copper.hat because the vector $w$ is not an eigenvalue. It is an eigenvector. Am I correct?

@Hope I do not understand your response. You can compute the eigenvalues and sum them to get the trace. Similarly you can find a basis in which the operator is triangular and this gives the eigenvalues. You could also find the characteristic polynomial from which you can determine the eigenvalues.

@Hope Note that ${u}^\bot$ is a subspace of dimension $n-1$, so $T$ has at least $n-1$ zero eigenvalues and so the trace is determined by the remaining eigenvalue. Noting that ${\cal R} T \subset \operatorname{sp} {w}$, the only  possible corresponding eigenvector is $w$. Since $Tw = \langle w,v \rangle w$, we see that the remaining eigenvalue is $\langle w,v \rangle$.

Let $u$ be an eigenvector of $T$ associated to a non-zero eigenvalue. Then by the definition of $T$, $u\in \text{Span}(w)$. Thus if there is a non-zero eigenvalue, it is of multiplicity $1$, associated to the eigenvector $w$. We deduce that when $w$ and $v$ are not orthogonal, $\langle w,v\rangle$ is the only non-zero eigenvalue of $T$, and is of multiplicity $1$. If $w$ and $v$ are orthogonal, then $T^2 = 0$ and $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$. In any case, $\text{Tr}(T) = \langle w,v\rangle$.
Another way to solve this problem, similar to what you did: If $w$ is orthogonal to $v$, then $T^2 = 0$ and $\text{Tr}(T) = 0$. We now suppose $\langle w,v\rangle \neq 0$. We write $n = \dim V$ and we complete $(w)$ into a basis $(w,b_2,...,b_n)$ of $V$. Denoting $\forall k\in \{2,\dots,n\}$, $c_k = b_k - \frac{\langle b_k, v\rangle}{\langle w, v\rangle} w$, we get that $C = (w,c_2,\dots,c_n)$ is a basis of $V$. Then the matrix representation of $T$ in base $C$ is
$$\mathcal {Mat}_C(T) = \begin{pmatrix}\langle w, v\rangle & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \ddots & \vdots\\\vdots& \ddots &\ddots & \vdots\\ 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Immediately $\text{Tr}(T) = \langle w, v\rangle$.
Note that replacing $b_k$ with $c_k$ is unnecessary, I just did it to have a diagonal representation of $T$.
Edit: On the question of why $T^2 = 0$ when $\langle w,v\rangle = 0$:
Suppose that $\langle w,v\rangle = 0$. Then $T(w) = \langle w,v\rangle w = 0$. Then for any $u\in V$, $T^2(u) = T(\langle u,v\rangle w) = \langle u,v\rangle T(w) = 0$. Thus $T^2 = 0$.

why do we need $T^2$ in your second solution?

@Hope Only to well-define $c_k$. You can do a different case distinction, with either $w = 0$ ($T = 0$) or $w\neq 0$, the latter only allows you do make a matrix representation of $T$ in basis $B = (w,b_2,\dots,b_n)$ as $c_k$ cannot be defined anymore. But this gives you a matrix representation with the first row being the only non-zero row, so a triangular matrix, which allows you to compute the trace nonetheless. Note that $T$ isn't diagonalizable when $w\neq 0$ and $\langle w,v\rangle = 0$, but this doesn't stop you from finding the trace as I mentionned.

I mean in your first line in the second solution you said $T^2 = 0$ why?

@Hope I have edited my answer to answer your question.
